# Neo4J return list of all labels linked with one specific node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Where the below cypher commmand gives a list of all nodes

```
match(n) return distinct labels(n), count(*)
```

I want to do the same but for one node eg.

```
match(p:Person {name: "dave"} return distinct labels(n), count(*)
```

I've tried this but it only returns a count of one

I need a list with label totals under this person

```
**labels(n)**          **count(*)**
['Address']              2
['jobs']                 1
['cars']                 3
```

Comment: What does your graph look like? Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to get the labels of all nodes that are connected by a relationship to a specific person? If so, do you just nodes that are directly connected to that person, or do you want to follow all paths from the person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help but this still returns a count of 1. I've just worked out how to get what I needed: 
`Match (p:Person{name:"dave"})-[*]->(c) return distinct labels(c), count(*)`

Answer (score 2):

`match(p:Person {name: "dave"} return distinct labels(n), count(*)`

is counting the number of row (Without aggregation, it will always be 1). You are returning the labels as an array, so what you really want is the array length

`match(n) return distinct labels(n), SIZE(LABELS(n))`

Based on your question I think you actually want to unwind the labels like this

`match(n) UNWIND LABELS(n) as label WITH label RETURN DISTINCT label, count(label)`

Comment: Thanks Tezra, but your unwinding the labels gives me all labels on the database I want the same format but want labels connected to one specific node

Comment: @LateDeveloper That would be the same query, just replace `(n)` with `(n:Person {name: "dave"})`

Comment: Hi Tezra, thanks for your help but this still returns a count of 1.
I've just worked out how to get what I needed:
`Match (p:Person{name:"dave"})-[*]->(c) return distinct labels(c), count(*)`